# App does not go back even though parent activity has been defined in manifest

Tags: android

I have defined a toolbar and initialized it. It works fine. I also set:

```
mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.create_acc_tool);
setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create An Account");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and defined the respective parent activity in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginEmail"
     android:parentActivityName=".activities.LoginActivity"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

But when I click on back it just exits the app, I don't think it crashes

Logcat:

```
    08-31 16:53:03.473 4961-5410/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(4): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 7 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 3 3 gsm|lte level=3 voicelevel=3 datalevel=3
08-31 16:53:04.050 535-535/? I/MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ65 from CPU2 to CPU3
08-31 16:53:04.078 5801-6546/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=4 phoneId=0
08-31 16:53:04.079 5801-6546/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=4 retVal=false
08-31 16:53:04.083 4961-5495/? D/TelephonyManager: getDataEnabled: retVal=false
08-31 16:53:04.096 5801-12753/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=4 phoneId=0
08-31 16:53:04.096 5801-12753/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=4 retVal=false
08-31 16:53:04.097 4961-5495/? D/TelephonyManager: getDataEnabled: retVal=false
08-31 16:53:04.307 4961-4961/? I/StatusBarIconController:  appTransitionPending
08-31 16:53:04.314 11083-11248/example.com.groupeasy E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-31 16:53:04.314 11083-11248/example.com.groupeasy D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
08-31 16:53:04.320 4961-4961/? I/StatusBarIconController:  appTransitionPending
08-31 16:53:04.321 11083-16846/example.com.groupeasy V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3904
08-31 16:53:04.325 11083-16846/example.com.groupeasy V/FA: Activity paused, time: 281595996
08-31 16:53:04.332 11083-16846/example.com.groupeasy D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=3904, _sc=LoginEmail, _si=7142922541270458076}]
08-31 16:53:04.384 5315-16849/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=3904, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginEmail, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7142922541270458076}]
08-31 16:53:04.394 4961-4961/? I/StatusBarIconController: appTransitionStarting
08-31 16:53:04.395 5315-16849/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: user_engagement(_e), 65
08-31 16:53:04.396 5315-16849/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='example.com.groupeasy', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=3904, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginEmail, firebase_screen_id(_si)=7142922541270458076}]}
08-31 16:53:04.398 5315-16849/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 205375
08-31 16:53:04.398 11083-11083/example.com.groupeasy V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-31 16:53:04.401 5315-16849/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-31 16:53:04.406 5315-16849/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 22
08-31 16:53:04.452 11083-11250/example.com.groupeasy E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-31 16:53:04.452 11083-11250/example.com.groupeasy D/AppTracker: App Event: start
```

Comment: Here is my login activity manifest `<activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: Solved this myself
`Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent); 
finish();`
was missing the `finish()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved, I Just had to `finish()` the activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent); 
finish();
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

When you using the [android:parentActivityName](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent) attribute, it makes your code checking for `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

So, you need to check for it, with something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
  case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Read more at [Navigate Up To Parent Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp).

Comment: This does not work, I tried implementing the code, but the back button still does the same.

Comment: The issue was solved, I Just had to finish() the activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();